# Use methods from other files NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I want to use some methods from other files. The only problem that I have is that the files using some other parameters already.

This is the file that I want to use. It is going to have some methods for my api calls. Models are my database models that I pass, and app is express() itself. The file is called test.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

module.exports = function (app, models) {

    router.put('/', function (req, res) {

    });

    function test(){

    };


    return router;
};
```

Now I want to call the test method from this file.
So I created this, but this is not working. I get the error test is not a function.

```
const testFile = require('test');

    module.exports = function (app, models) {

        router.get('/', function (req, res) {
           testFile.test();
        });


        return router;
    };
```

And this is my index.js:

```
app.use('/api/test', require('./routes/test.js')(app, models));
app.use('/api/main', require('./routes/main.js')(app, models));
```

What is the correct way to call method test from my other file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are exporting a function which in turn returns only route and not the function test. To access test function you need to do in this way,

```
module.exports = function(app, models) {
   router.put('/', function (req, res) {

   });

   function test() {};

   return {
     router: router,
     testFun: test
   };
}
```

And in another file

```
const testFile = require('test')(app, models); // Correct path from current directory    

module.exports = function (app, models) {

    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
       testFile.testFun();
    });


    return router;
};
```